# making sure a generated array key is unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$array = array(
    "one" => "bar",
    "two"    => "21",
    "three"    => "22",
    "four"    => "25",
    "five" => array(
         "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         ),
        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         )),
    "six" => "et",
    "seven" => "op",
    "eight" => "hjs",
    "nine" => array(
         "1" => array(
             "ar5" => "food",
             "ar87" => "dr",
             "ar21" => "ch",
             "ar443" => "ju"
         ),
         "2" => array(
             "73" => "food",
             "82" => "dr",
             "90" => "ch",
             "2123" => "ju"
         )),
    "ten" => "bar",
    "eleven" => "bar",
    "twelve" => "bar"
);
```

and i want to make sure that every new array added must have a unique array key.To do that,i first get all the keys of the others i.e `$array['nine']` in my case then run a function until a unique key is found.

To add a new array to `$array['nine']` and to get all the keys in `nine`

```
$keyedd = array_keys($array['nine']);

$appendThis[''.unique_array_key($keyedd).''] = array(
             "73" => "nitrous",
             "82" => "oxide",
             "90" => "laughing",
             "2123" => "gas"
             );

$array['nine'] =  $array['nine'] + $appendThis;
```

This is the function

```
function unique_array_key($the_array){
$r = rand();
if (array_key_exists("$r", $the_array)) {
    unique_array_key($the_array);
}
else if(!array_key_exists("$r", $the_array)) {
    echo $r;
}
}
```

Once i run this

```
[nine] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ar5] => food
                    [ar87] => dr
                    [ar21] => ch
                    [ar443] => ju
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [73] => food
                    [82] => dr
                    [90] => ch
                    [2123] => ju
                )

            [] => Array
                (
                    [73] => nitrous
                    [82] => oxide
                    [90] => laughing
                    [2123] => gas
                )

        )
```

the newly added array do not have an array key.However,`unique_array_key($keyedd);` on its own seems to work fine.Why is the function not adding a unique key?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `echo $r;` with `return $r;`:

```
function unique_array_key($the_array){
   $r = rand();
   if (array_key_exists("$r", $the_array)) {
     return unique_array_key($the_array);
   } else {
     return $r;
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer internal PHP functionality for unique key generation:

```
$appendThis[uniqid()] = array(
    "73"   => "nitrous",
    "82"   => "oxide",
    "90"   => "laughing",
    "2123" => "gas"
);
```

No needs to reinvent wheel. Check documentation for [uniqid()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function.

**Update**
If you have web-cluster running your application simultaneously on several hosts with shared data storage, and more than 10000 ID generations in one second just use:

```
uniqid(php_uname('n'), true)
```

for ID generation. Your solution with `rand()` ID generation have only `mt_getrandmax()` variations. Usually it is 2147483647. With 10000 ID generations in sec you'll get exceed available ID's limit in [**2.4 days**](http://codepad.org/Pysclgnz), and your code will run in infinite loop because every key check in array will have true result and recursively call new ID generation again and again.

Also, your solution make the application performance dependent on data amount. Than more data you'll have, than higher chance of additional loops for ID generation because of duplicates. For example, if you'll have **N** already stored arrays with unique ID's, there is a chance next ID will be generated for **N+1** cycles.

If your project not highload, will be enough `uniqid()` or `uniqid('', true)` if you need additional entropy.

Comment: Is have no guarantee that my user will be at the same host,say 3 days after `uniqid()` was run so if php is some how logging all runs of `uniqid()` by host,then it might not work for me.

Comment: Your application will be work simultaneously on one host or on several hosts?

Comment: Its portable so it might be several hosts.

Comment: It doesn't matter is it portable. If your application run on one host with only one bound data storage you can use `uniqid()`. If your application run on web-cluster that contains several hosts with shared data storage there is small probability run `uniqid()` in same time, because `uniqid()` result depends on current time. In that case you must use `uniqid(php_uname('n'), true)` syntax to reduce chance of non-unique id generation.